# How to add _ to white spaces in json objects?

Tags: php

I am loading json this way:

```
  $json = file_get_contents("world_ita.json");
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
```

But the file has "United States" or "British Islands"

I need to parse the doc in order to replace all white spaces with an underscore and have it:

```
United_States or British_Islands
```

Comment: if you need  change all the space on $json apply the answer  by Evert to $json and  after decode

Comment: What do you mean with "the file has"? Strings with spaces are not illegal in JSON in any way! However, read and understand [mcve], without that your question is off-topic anyway.

Comment: Well, maybe you should then clarify what exactly you want and at what place exactly your unable to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = str_replace(' ', '_', $input);
```

Comment: so       `$data = str_replace(' ', '_', $input);` right ?

Comment: no, `str_replace` only works on strings. Do it only on the specific bits of data you're interested in.

Comment: based on the code on the question the how would I approach it? I know in js not in php

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data. Try looping through it.